How to obtain an HBITMAP of the date and time displayed in the taskbar on Windows 11/10?
I am attempting to retrieve an HBITMAP of the date and time displayed in the taskbar on Windows 11/10. Specifically, I need to access the container or window that contains this information programmatically.
I tried accessing the TrayClockWClass, but it did not work as expected. I couldn't find relevant information on MSDN or other sources regarding this specific taskbar element. I expected to find a straightforward method or API to retrieve the HBITMAP or at least the name of the container/window where the date and time are displayed.

Why would that be useful?

It's a feature in my program. One mode takes regular screen captures. The other mode overlays the current time from the taskbar onto the last capture.

"I expected to find a straightforward method or API to retrieve the HBITMAP or at least the name of the container" - Why would you expect either of those to be exposed by the OS? In any case, you don't need to capture an image of the Taskbar's clock. Just retrieve the current date/time from the GetLocalTime() API and then draw it onto your captured image however you want.

It's for a cheat program for "educational purposes". The goal is to make it look like the screenshot is current, so overlaying the actual taskbar clock image is important to avoid detection.

Why don't you take a screenshot as usual, and copy a rectangle into future screen shots? Or you could copy the whole taskbar to save fiddling around by trial and error to figure out exactly where the time is.

You can use UI Automation to determine the location and size of the system clock. You can use this information to subsequently capture this portion of the screen. Doing this from C is possible but rather involved.

But the problem is, let's say the cheat mode is active for 5 minutes, then in reality 5 minutes would have passed, but not on the images, and I would have to program it differently for each screen resolution. I want to find a dynamic way to program it so that it works almost always.

Isn't there a simpler way to find all child windows or containers in the taskbar first, like getting their names or handles? Or should I reverse engineer the program responsible for the taskbar?

"Isn't there a simpler way to find all child windows or containers in the taskbar" - This assumes there were child windows. I doubt this is the case in Windows 10 and it becomes ever more unlikely with newer versions of Windows. Some problems don't have simple solutions.

I don't get the problem. You can take a screenshot, and get an HBITMAP. Then 5 minutes later take another screen shot and copy a rectangle from the first one on to the later one.

Alternatively, leave the area covered by the system clock transparent in your fake desktop overlay. That lets you display a fake desktop without having to do anything else for the system clock to show updates. As an added bonus your fake desktop is now able to span multiple displays that potentially show the system clock multiple times at potentially different resolutions.

@WeatherVane The problem is that the program is not my own. I wrote a DLL injection that hooks the screenshot function, and the screenshot function takes a screenshot every second.

@IInspectable I understand what you mean by making the area transparent, but there’s a problem. The program takes a screenshot every second. In cheat mode, it takes a normal screenshot and then overwrites all pixels except the system clock with pixels from the old screenshot to keep the time current.
Even if I make the old screenshot’s clock area transparent, I don’t know the exact size of this area due to different resolutions. I haven't been able to determine the size of this area reliably.

UI Automation allows you to discover the area(s) covered by the system clock(s). You can use the inspect.exe tool to familiarize yourself with the data available through MSAA/UIA. Do not underestimate the amount of work required to pull this prank off.

@IInspectable Thank you for your help. I will look into this using the inspect.exe tool and MSAA/UIA data.
